# Why does the docx js api work on jsfiddle (or other similar sites) but not when I load it via Tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

I'm currently at a beginner level in writing Javascript and have been doing a lot of self-learning over the past few months. Now, I am trying to create an automated script using Tampermonkey in order to create doc files at work. The API that I want to use to accomplish this is docx (https://docx.js.org/).

My issue is the following:

I am trying out a bit of code to test the functionality of the API, and so I just wanted to create a simple blank file, then save it to my computer to make sure that it works. So, I went to `jsFiddle` and wrote out some simple code to attach to a button to save a doc file. The code works, and a blank file is generated and is saved onto my computer.

Now I head over to Tampermonkey and insert the same code, but when I try it out in the browser, it doesn't work, and no errors are logged. Through much digging, I *think* I was able to find the reason for why the code isn't working. One of the functions in the API, which converts the file I created into a Blob so that I can then download it as a doc file, returns a Promise. In the console, when I run the code in `jsfiddle`, I see that the status of the Promise is "resolved". When I run the code outside on any page, the status is always "pending".

The code also successfully runs in sites similar to `jsfiddle`, such as codepen, repl, etc. I've tried many suggestions such as having the code run once the page has finished loading (using `window.onload`, `$(document).ready()`), but nothing works. I'm not sure what else `jsfiddle` does to my code that makes it execute correctly. Could it be Tampermonkey? Here is the code on `jsfiddle` for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/jcor19/qz8n4wmu/

And here is the Tampermonkey script code:

```
    // ==UserScript==
// @name         Test Script
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      1.0
// @author       me
// @match        http://e-try.com/black.htm
// @require      https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js
// @require      https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js
// @require      https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.8/FileSaver.js
// @require      https://unpkg.com/docx@5.0.0-rc5/build/index.js
// ==/UserScript==

jQuery(function() {
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = "Do Something";

    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    body.appendChild(button);

    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
        const doc = new Document();

        Packer.toBlob(doc).then(blob => {
            console.log(blob);
            saveAs(blob, "example.docx");
            console.log("Document created successfully");
        });
    });
});
```

Thank you for taking a look!

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I'm seeing exactly the same thing.

I believe it's something to do with the sandbox vs native page execution environments.

I've tried a bunch of different ways of injecting code that looks like your minimal docx js example above into both sides and nothing works.

Just left with a hanging promise.